# How can I prevent signing in into application with signed out authentication cookie?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies, penetration-testing

**Scenario:**
I have two users (User1 and User2) who can sign in into the application.

When User1 sign in into the application, its authentication cookies are created.
I copy these cookies and save it in notepad & log out the User1's account.

Then User2 sign in into application and these newly created cookies for User2 are *replaced* with User1's cookies (that were saved in notepad earlier)
and when I refresh the page User2 is getting replaced by User1

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
        var cookiesToBeDeleted = Request.Cookies.Keys;
        foreach (string cookie in cookiesToBeDeleted)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
        }
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

The above code (C#) deletes the cookies after logout, but what if cookies are copied before they are deleted & reused again before there expiration time.

How can I prevent this reuse of signed out user's cookies.

*Note: I am not willing to use database for this purpose*

Comment: Short answer: You can’t. Cookie-based identities contain everything in the cookie, and signing out just means discarding the cookie. There is no mechanism to invalidate this cookie without storing the user session also on the server-side which is opposite to the idea behind claims-based authentication. – Usually, cookie stealing is not a practical attack vector since it requires access to the user’s machine. And if you have that, you have better means for identity theft.